# Barplotting survey results with axes switched

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart, survey

My level of R expertise is *25% into "R for Everyone"*, which is insufficient for my first real-world task:

> 48 people were asked to memorize and recall 10 digits. Now the results
>   should be presented in a bar plot with the number of responses on the
>   X axis and the number of memorized digits - on Y.

---

Here's what I did by now:

```
responses <- c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,2,2,2,2,2,2,6,6,6,6,8,8,8,8,4,4,4,7,7,9)
# 10 people recalled 10 digits, 11 people - 3 digits, 7 people 5 digits, etc
```

I tried `plot(responses)`. The resulting graphic was entirely off my goal.

I tried `qplot` and `barplot`, but I don't know how to switch axes (not to make the graph horizontal, but to swap X and Y).

Then I thought that I should treat `responses` as a factor. But `ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class factor`. Also, I don't know how to formulate "*show factor levels on the X axis and the depth of each level on Y*".

Then I converted `responses` to a single-column `data.frame`, which, coupled with ggplot2, delivered almost palatable results:

```
df <- data.frame(responses)
ggplot(df, aes(df$responses)) + geom_bar(binwidth=.5,fill="#56B4E9") + xlab("Digits memorized") +    ylab("# of responses") + ggtitle("10 digit memorization experiment results") + scale_x_continuous( breaks = round( seq( min(df$responses), max(df$responses), by = 1 ), 1) ) + theme_economist() + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0:11)) + theme(axis.title=element_text(size=14))
```

[image: The output of the code above. orig from: i.imgur.com/XxO9y6P.jpg]

**Why this graph is not what I need**:

- The number of responses should be on the X axis, while the number of digits memorized — on Y. (Then the distribution will be more obvious.)

In the code above, I would gladly replace `ggplot(df, aes(df$responses))` with `ggplot(df, aes(df$something_else))`, but the `responses` column is all I have.

---

**I tried**. What you see above is a shadow of what I have been trying for the last 3 days. Unfortunately, most of my trying boils down to following my own tracks into the same dead ends.

**I searched**. What I found were 2 categories of solutions: either for multiple columns/variables, which I don't understand how to apply to my one-column data.frame; or the ones assuming more knowledge.

I would be grateful for any hint.

Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either the base graphics function `barplot()`

```
barplot(table(responses), horiz=T, xlab="Count",ylab="Digits Mem")
```

[image]

or ggplot with `coord_flip()`

```
ggplot(data.frame(resp=factor(responses)), aes(resp)) + 
    geom_bar() + coord_flip() +
    ylab("Count") + xlab("Digits Mem")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and expertise. Is there a way to plot my data not by `responses`, but by the _count_ of each response? See here: http://i.imgur.com/MaLbgYj.png (This is what I tried to ask initially.)

Comment: That is what's plotted here. For example, three people memorized 4 digits in your data. The number of digits (4) is on the y-axis, and the number of people (3) is the x axis value for the third bar from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this unadorned histogram?

```
responses <- c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,2,2,2,2,2,2,6,6,6,6,8,8,8,8,4,4,4,7,7,9)
df <- data.frame(responses  = responses)
```

library("ggthemes")

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = responses)) +
  geom_histogram(stat = "bin", color = "blue") +
  theme_tufte() +
  labs(x = "Digits Memorized", y = "Number of Subjects") +
  ggtitle("Count of Participants Per Digits Memorized") +
  annotate("segment", x = 4.5, xend = 8.5, y = 5.646, yend = 5.646, width =3) +
  annotate("text", x = 6.5, xend = 8.5, y = 6, yend = 6, label = "Average = 5.5")
```

[image]

Comment: Just thought you might like to see some of the other things to be done with ggplot (change themes, colors, add lines and annotate them (latter done with sumary(responses) by the way.

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, you should accept it, or upgrade it at least.

Comment: I clicked the ✔ next to that answer — will this work?

Comment: Yes, you clicked the other answer.